# how to read text written on this light bulb

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have an image of a light bulb like this:

[image]

and I want to extract the number writen on it:

[image]

then pass to ocr.

how can I do this with OpenCV?

I have written code like this, but it didn't good for ocr.

```
def img_process(frame):
    original_frame = frame.copy()
    rected = frame.copy()
    add_rect(rected)

    croped = crop(frame)
    frame_grey = cv2.cvtColor(croped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(frame_grey.copy(), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 13, 8)
    final = remove_lines(thr)
    final = cv2.morphologyEx(final, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((2, 2)))
    cnts, hiercachy = cv2.findContours(final, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    sorted_contours= sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse= True)
    if len(sorted_contours) > 0:
        largest_item= sorted_contours[0]
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_item)
        cv2.rectangle(final, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0,0), 2)

    return rected, final


def remove_lines(img_thr):
    # Remove horizontal
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10, 3))
    detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thr, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:


        cv2.drawContours(img_thr, \[c\], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)

    # Remove vertical
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 10))
    detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thr, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts\[0\] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts\[1\]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(img_thr, \[c\], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)

    return img_thr
```

original image with rectangle on it to locate the camera on the code:

[image]

cropped and processed image:

[image]

Comment: this isn't an OpenCV problem, it's an OCR problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz do you mean that my processed image is ok for the OCR?

Comment: I mean: preprocessing is counterproductive with modern OCR. the OCR knows better than you how to handle the input. also, that picture is hard to read as is. no preprocessing will improve this. also, your entire code doesn't contain any attempt to use OCR. this leads me to believe you haven't worked on this question sufficiently to ask it. please review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I didn't add the code used for ocr. I used tesseract but did not work good. Do you know other tools?

Comment: @AliPirpiran you might inspect the HSV ranges, and do threshold using `inRange()` to extract the largest connected silver colored zone, after that processing the image/text will be easier.

Comment: I think this is a question of how to properly take a picture of the text on the bulb. If I can’t read it, OCR isn’t going to be able either.

Comment: Perhaps unwrap the text on the lightbulb with the inverse of a cylindrical wrap

Comment: before you consider any of those filtering recommendations, deal with the reflective surface. that requires physical changes, not digital filters.

Comment: As far as the physical side of this, I've done jewelry engraving work before, and one thing that I've done if I can't see what's engraved very well (because it's faded over time) is I'll put a yellow sticky note underneath the ring as I'm examining it, and the engraving becomes readable right away. Consider putting a sheet of paper underneath the number before taking a picture, it might clarify the design. Maybe something like a sticky note with a hole for the light bulb to go into? Experiment with different colors of paper. Also experiment with the  angle of the camera relative to the light.